# How to change Pydantic default __root__ example

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

So I have this class:

```
class Table(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[int, Test]
```

and I'm using the `__root__` since it is a dynamic value but when I go to `/redoc` (I'm using FastAPI) the example values it defaults to is `property1`, `property2` as in the image below but I wanted the default example to be `id_1`, `id_2` for example. How can I achieve this?

[image]

I tried changing the alias and title using the Field method of the library but didn't seem to work like I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing it with the [schema customization](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#schema-customization) ?

```
class QcastTable(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[int, Test]

       class Config:
           schema_extra = {
               "examples": [
                   {
                       "id_1": {
                           "title": "yourTitle",
                           "description": "yourDescription",
                       },
                       "id_2": {
                           "title": "yourTitle2",
                           "description": "yourDescription2",
                       }
                   }
               ]
           }
```

Comment: Hi @eychef thats a great idea but I was wondering if its possible for me to preserve the underlying class structure instead of needing to define my self the hole example?

Comment: The main reason for my follow up question is because I have like more 4 classes for that Model and manually making examples is not efficient if later on we need to expand.

Comment: Sadly I don't know how you could achieve the desired example output without either using the `schema_extra` or PyDantic's  `Field` class ('examples' attribute). Sorry